# Is relative CSS positioning faster than JS positioning?

Tags: javascript, css, performance

I am wondering if JS is slower in determining certain values than CSS, because they both would have to do the same calculatios.

In other words, if I set a margin in `%` to an element, it will use the width of its parent as a base. For instance, `margin: 50% = margin: 0.5 * parent.width`. Internally, then, the browser has to *calculate* the correct margin based on the parent's width, right? How then, is this different from calculating in JS? Why is CSS faster? What internal CSS rendering makes these computational processes faster than JS can do?

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/jvknpswh/). Both child divs are the same, but one div's margin is calculated in CSS (`margin: 20%`) and the other in JS:

```
var $cont = $("#container");
$("#js").css("margin", $cont.width() * 0.2);
```

Considering resize: the CSS engine will have to re-calculate the margin as well on resize, right?

Considering load time: I am only talking about the actual execution time. In other words:

```
var $cont = $("#container");
    $("#js").css("margin", $cont.width() * 0.2);
```

vs.

```
#css {margin: 20%;}
```

Excluding any additional (library) load times. The difference between jQuery and vanilla JS shouldn't be included in the answer. I am aware of performance differences between the two.

Comment: Calling JS functions is a bit slow. And lots of `resize` events are fired simultaneously. So using a `resize` event listener may be slower.

Comment: My guess would be slower, as that js call happens after the page loads

Comment: @Oriol See my edit. Wouldn't the CSS rendering engine have to recalculate the margins as well?

Comment: @BramVanroy Yes, but in CSS this can be done internally, without calling functions. And if you use jQuery, JS will be slower almost surely.

Comment: Do you think `$('#js').css('margin','20%')` is any faster?

Comment: @vol7ron Hm, good question. I would assume that jQuery only inserts that rule and that the CSS engine calculates the correct pixel values.

Comment: @Oriol That's basically what my question comes down to: *what does a CSS engine have internally that makes these calculations faster in CSS*. Could you go in more detail than "without calling functions"?

Comment: One of the things is that CSS doesn't do calculations here, from a certain kind of POV. The internal browser engine can parse the CSS file once and then store the element sizes in its most central kind of core data structures and then perform the calculations however it wants at exactly the most appropriate time without triggering callbacks or anything of that sort. Here the more rigid/static nature of CSS has a kind of special privilege of working at the heart of the browser where the browser developers can obsess about speeding it up, whereas JS kind of has to run on top.

Comment: So crudely speaking, CSS specifies properties that are completely native and implemented at the heart of the browser. It might be a domain specific language, but it's a limited one specifying very native details to a browser. JS is kind of a foreign entity, allowed to do a much wider range of things, so the browser devs can't make so many assumptions about it and it has to kind of float on top. So there tends to be a greater runtime overhead that you can't optimize away if you're a browser developer.

Comment: CSS is way faster, mainly because it does a lot less work, it's rules are cached in "C++ memory space", and it's instructed ahead of time, so that it can integrate with pre-rendered layers and other sub-screen optimizations.

Comment: @@BramVanroy my question above was a little satiric, of course in the case you gave, CSS would be faster; if not because the JS would be processing extra instructions to determine the container width. (leaving jQuery performance out of it)
@dandavis The question, in my mind, comes down to if a fixed number calculated via JavaScript is any faster than a percentage calculated by CSS?  It'd be almost negligible, but the CSS would probably be faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question will have somewhat of a vague answer since it's extremely browser-dependent. However, it's probably fairly safe to say that CSS is generally going to be faster here.

The first thing to note is that we are not comparing the speed of CSS as a language to JavaScript, per se. CSS isn't necessarily `executed` repeatedly in this sense. Its focus is on specifying properties that are very native to the heart of the browser. The browser can parse it once and then do whatever it wants with that specification. In fact, it would generally be a rather poor browser if it's repeatedly checking/executing the same unchanging CSS code over and over.

So one way to look at this is that we aren't really asking why CSS is faster than JavaScript. CSS is not the one doing the calculations here. We're asking why a native web browser can be faster than the client-side JavaScript it can run on top.

If you put yourself in a browser developer's shoes, you can see a specification when parsing the CSS file initially that an element is supposed to have a relative size that is 50% of its parent.

You're now allowed to do whatever you want with the specification as the page is redrawn, scrolled, interacted with. You can store that size specification at the heart of your core data structures and even use metal-scraping assembly code if you want. You can calculate the new absolute sizes of such relative-sized children in a single pass descending down the hierarchy from parent to child. You can calculate the absolute pixel sizes of 4 children at once using SIMD. You can do anything given that initial property specification.

With JavaScript, we have no such control. The client-side script can do anything here, so we have to trigger a resize event and if the JS side resizes things inside a resize event, it might trigger a whole cascade of such events and possibly even reset/interfere with the regular process of calculating client rectangles. The size of an element, even at the percentage level, turns into a blank, a giant question mark that has to be repeatedly 'queried' in a sense. This is all speculative as it's very browser-dependent.

But what isn't browser-dependent is that CSS allows those kinds of browser-native optimizations given its static, predictable, property-specifying nature. JS has a lot more freedom, and so it has to run on top and can't have that kind of special privilege of allowing the browser developers to do whatever they want with it.

With CSS, the ball is in the native browser developers' court. With JS, the ball is in your court, and it's going to be quite difficult (if even possible) to beat the browser developers given that the JS code is running on top of the browser.

Answer (score 1):

1) In the end, it's all CSS positioning. Calculating it in JS, versus letting the CSS + layout engine calculate it just means that once you have the number, you need to assign it to the element (or elsewhere) and have the CSS engine pick it up from there, and apply it during the next repaint.

2) The CSS has access, internally, to the actual pixel widths of things. There are times where you need to determine computed styles of elements, in order to make your calculations...

...that means you need to call a method which reads those values, parse them into workable numbers, do your calculations, convert back into the appropriate string representing the unit value, and send it back to CSS/layout/rendering.

This doesn't mean that JS can't be fast.
Likewise, there are things that JS can do, which CSS will never be able to do on its own (like advanced, dynamic animation-blending)...
...but the trick is to use both where appropriate, and for reasons well-described above, to know that something which you write to be run dozens of times a second, can't be compared to something which only needs to be calculated each time you touch something which invalidates the previous calculations, with the benefit of knowing that you can change minute details on a whim in the JS version, as well as compose all kinds of sequences, which can be decomposed and recomposed on the fly, where in CSS, you're at the mercy of the predefined animations.